# Checking if (discrete) signal is stationary, BIBO stable and

Tags: signal-processing

I have this discrete signal 
    y[n] = sum (x[k+1]h[k-1]), where k goes from -inf to +inf.

I need to check if this signal is stable, stationary, and if it's invertible, i need to find it's inverse signal.

Now, i know that signal is stable if for bounded input it produces bounded output, but i don't know how to apply it on this signal.

Also, i know that stationary signal is one that for moved input results with the output moves the same way (i hope i formulated that correctly).

Invertible signal means that based on the form of the output signal i can uniquely define the input signal.

But, again, i don't know how to test it, how to apply it for the given formula.
Any help on the matter would be appreciated.